# Create new Appointment with org-gcal

Tags: org-mode

I am using [org-gcal](https://github.com/myuhe/org-gcal.el) and want to sync my Gmail Calender with Emacs. The `from Google to Emacs` way seems to work really nice.
In addition I am using [calfw](https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-calfw) to view the appointments.

Is there an easy way to create a new appointment with predefined fields, like `subject`, `time` and so on, instead of manually create a todo in the gmail org file?

As proposed in the comments here is a sample appointment:

```
* Title
  :PROPERTIES:
  :LINK: [[https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=123456789][Go to gcal web page]]
  :ID: ukf76ifl27j3shea562f5vrhe0
  :END:      

  <2016-08-01 Mo 09:10-10:10>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I could not find anything in the READMEs of `calfw` and `org-gcal`

Comment: Please consider editing your post to include the **exact** format of an `org-mode` entry created by synchronizing a task/event from Google to Emacs.  Once that is done, someone in this forum can propose a sample addition to `org-capture-templates`.  This assumes that the library `org-gcal` has good support for a two-way/bi-directional sync.

Comment: I added it; also I am still new to org, how can I use templates to write to a specific org file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a proper solution:

I use the following template to write to my `gmail.org`. The neat thing is, as soon as I accept this template it automatically pushs it to Google.

```
* %^{Subject}
%^T

%^{Description}
```

I also got into the `org-capture` thing. I add the following thing to my config:

```
(with-eval-after-load 
    'org 
  (setq org-capture-templates
        '(
          ("g" "Gmail")
          ("ge" "Event" entry (file "~/Todo/gmail.org") 
           (file "~/Todo/.org-templates/event")
           :empty-lines-before 1))))
```

And the above template is just in the file `"~/Todo/.org-templates/event"`.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a template, but it's such a tiny thing, you might want to just hard code it into your entry for `org-capture-templates` and forget about a separate file containing just 4 lines.  But, if you really like having the existence of a separate file containing 4 lines, then more power to you.

Comment: I have actually many files for different kind of templates in a folder,  so this is nice to share

Answer (score 0):

You can start from setting below:

```
;;cfw:org-capture-template should be evaluated before requiring calfw-org
(setq cfw:org-capture-template
      '("c" "calfw2org" entry 
        (file "/path/to/your/gmail.org")
        "*  %?\n %(cfw:org-capture-day)"))

(require 'calfw-org)
```

With this setting, you can create new appointment by pressing "c" on the calfw view.

cf. http://sheephead.homelinux.org/2014/03/15/7035/ (Japanese)

Comment: This does not work for me.
`org-capture-select-template: No capture template referred to by "c" keys`
Not sure what's wrong yet.